# Passing arguments to package callback

Tags: python, callback

I'm using the [Pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) package to listen for keyboard key presses. It has a callback method for key presses which I've defined like so:

```
def on_press(key):
    print('{0} key pressed'.format(key.char))
    ...
    if key == ord('q'):
        exit(0)
        return
    # view.update_ui(player.get_metadata()) # how can I pass this in?
```

It is then hooked up to the listener and the listener started:

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```

This works great if the only argument is `key` as demonstrated in the Pynput documentation. However, I'd like for this function to take additional parameters, e.g. `def on_press(key, view, player)`. What is the most pythonic way to go about this?

Comment: `Listener` sends to it only `key` and it will not send any other data dynamically. You can only use `lambda` (or `partial`) to run with other values but it will use always the same values. Eventually you would have to send reference to list, dictionary,queue which content you can change in any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a factory function or `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial

def on_press(key, view, player):
    print('{0} key pressed'.format(key.char))
    ...
    if key == ord('q'):
        exit(0)
        return

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=partial(on_press, view=my_view, player=some_player))
listener.start()
```